# Why wp redirects me to wp-login.php when I visit a rewritten wp-admin URL?

Tags: wp-admin, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I have this rewrite rule

```
^dashboard(.*) wp-admin$1 [L]
```

and wp redirects me to wp-login.php when I try to visit /dashboard (even if I am logged in)

Any idea why this happen, and how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a redirect not just a rewrite:

```
^dashboard(.*) wp-admin$1 [L,R=301]
```

WordPress is using a hard coded search for `wp-admin` in the request URI.

Comment: but won't the redirect show me wp-admin in the URL?

Comment: Anyway I solved it.

Thanks to this http://mu.wordpress.org/forums/topic/11865#post-88451
(last comment)

This way I can have mydomain.com/dashboard/ instead of mydomain.com/wp-admin/

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it